# How do I disable auto-replacement of missing fonts in Inkscape 0.91?

Tags: fonts, inkscape

I am making files on two different PCs. We have a large package of fonts that we use, not all of them are installed on both machines. When we make a file on PC1 with a font that is not present on PC2, and open that file on PC2, Inkscape replaces the font with its determination of 'closest font'. PC2 is used to produce a physical item using the font, and it is not always caught that the font was not present, even though Inkscape does try to let you know if you happen to have the Text/Font view open.

Is there a way to turn off the auto-selection of closest font? I would be happy with either 1) No font being used at all, resulting in an empty or odd looking graphic on the screen or 2) the ability to select a default font, that we could make something that would stand out.

Comment: or convert the fonts to curves

Comment: You might generate symbolic links from one font to all non existing fonts with a script on the second machine, at least on Linux and I guess on BSD.

Answer (score 1):

You could try selecting all text and using Object  > Object to Path, to convert text into outlines.  Obviously the disadvantage here is that the text will no longer be editable as text, so make sure you don't overwrite your original SVG containing the original editable text.

Example of text turned into outlines.

[image]